# How to get rid of quotes in strings when using yaml.dump

Tags: python-3.x, string, aws-cloudformation, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I am trying to use ruamel.yaml to generate cloudformation YAML templates from ordered dictionary.
I need to prefix some of the strings with "`!Sub`" which is a cloudtemplate function reference in a way that it is not enclosed in quotes with the rest of the strings, e.g.:

```
Type: AWS::Glue::Job
Properties:
  Role2: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${GlueServiceRole}'
```

Test code I started with looks like this:

```
from ruamel import yaml
from collections import OrderedDict

def ordered_dict_presenter(dumper, data):
    return dumper.represent_dict(data.items())

test = OrderedDict(
    {
        "Type": "AWS::Glue::Job",
        "Properties": {
            "Name": "test_job",
            "Role": "!Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${GlueServiceRole}",
            "Role2": "Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${GlueServiceRole}",
        },
    }
)
yaml.add_representer(OrderedDict, ordered_dict_presenter)

print(yaml.dump(test, default_style=None, default_flow_style=False))
```

It outputs this yaml:

```
Type: AWS::Glue::Job
Properties:
  Name: test_job
  Role: '!Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${GlueServiceRole}'
  Role2: Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${GlueServiceRole}
```

It seems like when a string starts with non-alphabetic character it is automatically quoted.
I tried custom representers to get rid of quotes but without any luck so far. How can I output this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you really shouldn't be using the old API anymore, there has been a new one, which allows much more control
over what you are doing for several years now.

Second, you **cannot** put something that looks like a tag inside a string and
not get quotes, during loading that would load like a tag and you might want
that, but that would make an infinite number of strings (all those starting with
`!`) non-representable in YAML.

If you don't know where to start, the thing to do is try and round-trip (load then dump) your required result:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
Type: AWS::Glue::Job
Properties:
  Role2: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${GlueServiceRole}
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

this gives:

```
Type: AWS::Glue::Job
Properties:
  Role2: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${GlueServiceRole}
```

This confirms that ruamel.yaml can create the output. Now you only need to do that from scratch. For which you can
inspect `data` and especially `data['Properties']['Role2']` (if things don't round-trip that often but not   necessary, means
you cannot generate what you want, but find out how to do it in that case can be harder).

```
print(type(data['Properties']['Role2']))
```

This prints:

```
Type: AWS::Glue::Job
Properties:
  Role2: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${GlueServiceRole}
<class 'ruamel.yaml.comments.TaggedScalar'>
```

Now you only have to find out how TaggedScalar works ( source is in `comments.py`):

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

data = {}
data['Properties'] = props = {}
props['Role2'] = ruamel.yaml.comments.TaggedScalar('arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${GlueServiceRole}', style=None, tag='!Sub')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

giving:

```
Properties:
  Role2: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${GlueServiceRole}
```

Alternatively you can specify `style="'"` or `style='"'` if you do want to have quotes.

Comment: Thank you for the promptly answer. This is exactly the guidance I needed. For people who would be struggling like me, could you please paste some documentation reference on the new API. I was not able to find anything concise.

Comment: You're welcome, Basic documentation is on [readthedocs](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basicuse.html), but of course that can still be extended/improved upon. On the left hand side you'll see "Departure from previous API" and "Reason for API change" if you are interested while the functional API didn't suffice anymore.